# VSCode Arrow Scroll Speed

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode it's possible to scroll the editor using the arrow keys to shift the position of the cursor up or down.

Is there any way adjust the speed of arrow based scrolling that doesn't involve increasing the keyboard input repeat rate?

Windows 10
VSCode 1.64.2

Comment: Did you ever find any info about this?

Comment: @swandog no, no luck

Answer (score 6):

There is not option inside vscode to control arrow/key repeat speed or the delay until repeat duration right now.

But you can control it via your system settings:

**Mac:**
System Settings > Keyboard > "Key Repeat" and "Delay Until Repeat" slider

**Windows:** Go to Keyboard settings and look for "Repeat delay" and "Repeat rate"

**Ubuntu:** Settings > Universal Access > Typing > Repeat Keys

Comment: Unfortunately this will apply the repeat speed globally, and not just in VSCode

Comment: Yes thats correct!
The problem here is the architecture of the system:
ONLY when the System Detects a keypress, it will propagate it to the focused application (vscode). If the system itself has a slower key repeat recognition, the application won't have a faster one.

So I guess the goal has to be to change the system settings based on which window is focused. 
Maybe you can find such an application.